# Erro ShowDialog Windows Forms - " Não é possível executar a operação durante o redimensionamento de uma coluna de preenchimento automático"

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Estou tendo a seguinte mensagem de erro, que aparece de forma exporádica:

> Não é possível executar a operação durante o redimensionamento de uma coluna de preenchimento automático

O erro ocorre no `form.ShowDialog(this)` neste trecho do código:

```
private void buttonBoletas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            FormBoleta form = new FormBoleta(_context);
            **DialogResult drResult = form.ShowDialog(this);**
            if (drResult != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá você pode usar o DialogResult de outra forma. Você pode declara direto no  if.

```
private void buttonBoletas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            FormBoleta form = new FormBoleta(_context);

            if (form.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```